# Why angularjs uses foreach(object,func)/trim(str) etc in place of object.forEach/str.trim

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was going through code of angularjs, Inside ngList directive I have found that angularjs uses custom defined `foreach(object,func)/trim(str)` etc in place of javascript natively defined `object.forEach/str.trim` .

I just couldn't able to understand reason behind this. Wouldn't it cause memory leakage due to defining lots of unnecessary variables? 
Link to ngList directive code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2665

If anyone can shed some light on it, it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect such is *partially* to support pre-ES5 browsers (even as "recent" as IE8?) without shimming the Array prototype. *However, [`angular.forEach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) can also iterate normal objects*, just as [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) can; it is *not* a direct replacement and offers additional functionality.

There is no reason why Angular's forEach would result in any more "memory leaks" than using a native implementation - such concerns should be a secondary question/post. But briefly: There is *no* memory leak in either case because the callbacks are execute immediately and synchronously; object lifetimes are *not* extend indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the support of prototype on IE8. It certainly doesn't support it. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/ . Thanks for the answer.